# Is there an alternative to auditd enabling different log files per filters?

Tags: linux-audit

Auditd do not enable to log different filters in different files (cf [man pages](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/audit.rules.7.html)). Is there an alternative to it which makes it possible, in particular to separate accounts activities?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Send auditd logs to rsyslog
- Filter logs per uid and send logs to a specific file

  if $msg contains 'uid=500' then /var/log/uid/500